# How to download all MP3 URL as MP3 from a webpage using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, download, mp3

I'm trying to learn Python and I tried to write a code to download all the bible mp3 files from my church website where there's a list of mp3 hyperlinks such as:

Chapter 1, Chapter 2,3,4,5 and so on... [Reference link](https://ghalliance.org/resource/bible-reading)

I managed to get all the mp3 URL links to show on the shell after running my code but I can't seem to be able to download them at all.

Here's my code

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://ghalliance.org/resource/bible-reading')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('http.*\.mp3')):
    print(a['href'])
```

I did try using wget but I can't seem to get wget to work on my machine running VSCode Python 3.8.1 64-bit or conda 3.7.4... I've checked both conda cmd and cmd and it showed that I had wget in my system, I even manually download the wget.exe to my system32 directory but whenever I tried to run the

```
wget.download(url)
```

I always get an error message or something like wget has no attribute 'download' or whatnot.

I read a few beginner tutorials on using selenium, wget, beautifulsoup to download simple pictures, etc but I can't seem to incorporate their method to work on this specific problem of mine...cuz I'm still too new to programming in general, so I apologize for asking stupid dumb questions like these.

But now that I had all my MP3 URL links, so my question is:
how do I go about downloading them using Python?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attention Please:

- to download multiple files from same host you should use `requests.Session()` to maintain the `TCP` connection session instead of keep repeat an action of opening a `socket` and `closing` it.
- You should use a `stream=True` to be out of corrupted downloads.
- before writing the content you should check the status by using `.status_code` for the `response`.
- also are you aware that there's 2 file names is missed? which is `Chiv Keeb 22mp3` and `Cov Thawjtswj 01mp3` where the extension should be `.mp3`.

Below is the correct code to achieve your goal.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r = requests.get("https://ghalliance.org/resource/bible-reading/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

with requests.Session() as req:
    for item in soup.select("#playlist"):
        for href in item.findAll("a"):
            href = href.get("href")
            name = re.search(r"([^\/]+$)", href).group()
            if '.' not in name[-4]:
                name = name[:-3] + '.mp3'
            else:
                pass
            print(f"Downloading File {name}")
            download = req.get(href)
            if download.status_code == 200:
                with open(name, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(download.content)
            else:
                print(f"Download Failed For File {name}")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help explain your process... I'm still having a hard time following and making sense of a few of the symbols such as "([^\/]+$)"... Can you explain what those are?...I tried out your code and yes, it worked perfectly, so thank you for that.

Comment: @iGamers read the explanation here https://regex101.com/r/FEHUZk/1

Comment: Ah yes, ofc it's the overly complicated regular expression that's even harder to memorize than trig.

Answer (score 10):

As you already use library `requests`
You also can use `requests` for download mp3 (or any files)

Example like if you want to download file from URL `https://test.ghalliance.org/resources//bible_reading/audio/Chiv Keeb 01.mp3`

```
doc = requests.get(https://test.ghalliance.org/resources//bible_reading/audio/Chiv%20Keeb%2001.mp3)
```

If download successful. The mp3 content will store in `doc.content` then you need to open file and write data to that file.

```
with open('myfile.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(doc.content)
```

At this point you have mp3 with filename "myfile.mp3" but you may want to save to filename same as name in URL.

let extract filename from URL.

```
filename = a['href'][a['href'].rfind("/")+1:]
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(doc.content)
```

Now let put it all together.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://ghalliance.org/resource/bible-reading')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'http.*\.mp3')):
    filename = a['href'][a['href'].rfind("/")+1:]
    doc = requests.get(a['href'])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(doc.content)
```

Comment: OMG! It worked! Thank you so much! So that's where I'm missing, I've learned a lot just by reading your easy step-by-step work. I really appreciate your time to help... I can't do much to show my appreciation but I hope I'll be able to help someone else in the future.

Comment: Yuup! This was so helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```html
import requests
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
i=0
r = requests.get('https://ghalliance.org/resource/bible-reading')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('http.*\.mp3')):
    i=i+1
    url = a['href']
    file=url.split()[1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, f"{file}_{i}.mp3")
```

using `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=None)` allows to copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much also, though the @Audy's reply above already answer my question... I really appreciate your input into this problem of mine and thanks for showing me another alternative approach. I'll always be thankful.